# Sorting on an array column

Tags: mysql, sql

Are there any databases that have a well-defined behavior when sorting on an array column? For example, with mysql:

```
WITH sort (letter, number) AS (
    select 'a', 1 union select 'a', 2 union
    select 'b', 4 union select 'b', 5
) SELECT letter, json_arrayagg(number) ids from sort group by letter order by ids -- [ASC|DESC doesn't matter]

# letter, ids
a, [1, 2]
b, [4, 5]
```

Do other DBs have well-defined sorting for an array type, or how does that usually work? My hope was that one of them supported sorting an array 'as-if' it were cast to a string (without having to manually do that).

Comment: Sorting by array makes no sense. *well-defined behavior when sorting on an array column?* it is NOT well-defined. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=697aaf395aab49c96c249613203857c1

Comment: @Akina maybe not as a default...I suppose it makes sense if someone specifically casts it to a string and wants to see `['a','b']` before `['c','h']`, no?

Comment: JSON array column (it seems) is sorted by 1st element only (i.e. `ORDER BY json_array_column` is equal to `ORDER BY json_array_column.[0]`). Yes, you may use `CAST(ids AS CHAR)` - but you'll obtain simple CSV in which the numbers are converted into strings (of different length!), you'll have common "sort numbers as strings" problem.

Comment: @Akina ah I see -- good point, thank you!

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 . . . MySQL does not support arrays.  You are referring to a JSON value.  And JSON doesn't really have the concept of what you want.  There may be ways to convert it to a string.